In spring JPA after insert an entity, can I get related entities full informed?
I want to know if I can get a related entity full informed after save it in DB with only the necessary fields (related entity Id).
This is how the model is:
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableA")
public class TableA {
    ...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "tableB_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    TableB tableB;
    ...
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB")
public class TableB {
    ...
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "tableB", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<TableA> tableAElements;
    ...
}

Tables:
┌───────────┐          ┌───────────┐
│  TableA   │ n------1 │  TableB   │
├───────────┤          ├───────────┤
│ ...       │          │ tableB_id │
│ tableB_id │          │ name      │
└───────────┘          └───────────┘

This is the information I want to insert in DB:
{
    // table A information
    ...
    tableB: {
        id: 1
    }
}

The CrudRepository.save method returns an entity after insert it. So, after insert this entity using CrudRepository.save method, is possible to get TableB entity informed from DB?. Can I get the TableB's name attribute informed like this:
{
    // table A information
    ...
    tableB: {
        id: 1
        name: name One // this is returned from DB
    }
}


Your A->B mapping is set to be insertable=false, updatable=false, so are you really sending {tableB:{{id:1}} as part of your A JSON? You have other mappings to this fk for this to work that you aren't showing. But short, No, what you want isn't possible without you doing something on your end after the Spring call - you get the A instance you passed in otherwise (see JPA 'persist' which is what spring uses under the covers for 'inserts'). Try using a find method that refreshes A and specifies B is to be fetched with the A

"Your A->B mapping is set to be insertable=false, updatable=false, so are you really sending {tableB:{{id:1}} as part of your A JSON?"
Yes, I want insert an A entity with a tableB_id FK informed, but I don't want insert a TableB entity. This entity already exists.
"You have other mappings to this fk for this to work that you aren't showing"
The other mappings are not relevant to what I'm asking here. This bidirectional relationship works fine in any direction. When I ask for any entity, the related entity is informed, and it works fine too when I save a TableA entity.

That isn't what insertable=false means. They apply to the foreign key, so you need to make it writable (so set them both to true) for the foreign key to be set. If you don't want JPA to insert a new 'B', that is covered under the cascade operations on the mapping. Hence if you have a FK being set, you have other mappings and they may be relevant. I've already given you a solution though - force a refresh on A and it'll rebuild A from the DB, and then calling getB will force B to be fetched as well. A better solution though would be to find B yourself before saving A

Hello @Chris it is what I did (your suggestion about find B before saving A). But I still do not get what you said about insertable=false/true means. Could you elaborate a little bit more about it?
